# Why would Electron renderer look for modules in AppData when launched from VSCode

Tags: module, visual-studio-code, electron, require

I'm testing in Electron using VSCode (and this is all pretty new to me as a dev environment) and I can load electron-log in main.js, but in index.js inside the renderer I get this (with two folders renamed for security purposes--but it doesn't change the issue):

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'electron-log'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\elided\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at http://localhost/appFolder/index.js:4:13
```

I suspect the issue has more to do with VSCode than with Electron--but I've had issues with configuration-loading modules as well...there's a nice, fat folder with everything I need in it right under index.js, but for some reason, Electron reaches for C:\Users\...\AppData...*etc*.

This works:

```
const log = require(`${global.dir}/node_modules/electron-log`);
```

but it's not really what I'd like to do, since I can't guess how this will turn out in the actual deployment.

This *doesn't* work (because a respondent wanted to see code):

```
const log = require('electron-log');
```

Comment: BTW, the AppData path you see in the above stack trace is simply the location of the electron specific `require` code > `electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12`

Answer (score 0):

Without even a basic example of the code which is not working, it's hard to know what's going wrong.

However, seeing you doing things like `${global.dir}/node_modules` it makes me wonder whether you're building paths properly.

Firstly, you should be using the node.js [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to calculate paths. This will ensure get you valid paths and will automatically work on any OS. There is also a [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) variable which will always a string of the path to the directory which contains the current source file. You can then resolve paths like:

```
const path = require('path')
const index = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Well, it's just a plain old require in the renderer.  Not much to show really.  global.dir is __dirname exported from main.js.  The gist of my complaint isn't so much that I can't figure out how to modify the require--the problem is that main.js knows where to get the modules, but the corresponding renderer doesn't.  How could Electron manage with main but fail with the renderer?  Unless 'path' resolves to an internal, how can I trust that the render side will be able to resolve its location correctly? It's already showing problems, is it not?

Comment: If `require('electron-log')` works in the main process it should work in the renderer. Why don't you just use `__dirname` in the renderer too?